# How to make a list of objects which all inherit from one base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, inheritance

I have a main abstract class and 4 sub-classes which all inherit from the abstract class. 
I want to make a list in which an element may be any of these 4 classes.

Test1.h

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    virtual void someFunc();

    void getTest();
    void setTest(int test);

protected:
    int test;
};
```

Test2.h:

```
#include "Test.h"

class Test2 : public Test{
public:
    Test2();
    void someFunc();

    int otherFunc();

};
```

There is Test3, Test4 and Test5 as well...

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test1.h"
#include "Test2.h"
#include "Test3.h"
#include "Test4.h"
#include "Test5.h"

int main() {
    list<Test> testList; //does not work
    Test2 t = Test2();
    Test3 t3 = Test3();
    Test4 t4 = Test4();
    testList.push_back(t);
    testList.push_back(t4);
}
```

Is there a way to make one list which could contain all of these elements?

Comment: Do you want the list to own the objects (i.e. do you want them to be deleted when the list is deleted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a vector of base class `Test` pointers e.g. :

```
std::vector<Test*>
```

If you can I would rather recommend to use smart pointers e.g. :

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>>
```

Comment: It worked! Is there a way I can set the size of the vector to increase dynamically as elements get added, instead of having to set an initial size?

Comment: with `std::vector` you don't have to do increase the size yourself. [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) will do the work for you. So use definitely `std::vector` !

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't want the list to own the objects you can use a vector of base class pointers:

```
std::vector<Test*> testList;
Test2 t = Test2();
Test4 t4 = Test4();
testList.push_back(&t);
testList.push_back(&t4);
```

If you want the list to own the objects you need to allocate the objects dynamically, the base class will need to have a virtual destructor and you will need to remember to delete the pointers or use smart pointers:

```
class Test {
public:
    virtual void someFunc();
    virtual ~Test(){}
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>> testList;
testList.push_back(std::make_unique<Test2>());
testList.push_back(std::make_unique<Test4>());
```